# What is the PrimarySilo in a cluster?

Tags: orleans

Currently I am working with Orleans and I am wondering what exactly the PrimarySilo is in a cluster? My guess is that if I make a silo the PrimarySilo, by using the following piece of code for example:

```
...
        var primarySiloEndpoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, localPrimarySiloEndpoint);
        siloHostBuilder.UseDevelopmentClustering(primarySiloEndpoint)
                       .Configure<EndpointOptions>(options => options.AdvertisedIPAddress = IPAddress.Loopback);
...
```

Then I am actually configuring what `ip:port` the cluster it self is listening on, since clients talk to silos and not clusters ? Can a cluster have multiple primary silos for example? I guess not.

Answer (score 0):

See point 6 [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/orleans/implementation/cluster-management#membership-table) in the documentation.

In summary, this term is only applicable for development clustering.